# how to compare two string arrays without java utils

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Check to see if the array arr1 contain the same elements as arr2 in the same order in java.

for example:

```
    isTheSame({"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}) → true
    isTheSame({"1", "2", "3"}, {"2", "1", "1"}) → false
    isTheSame({"1", "2", "3"}, {"3", "1", "2"}) → false
```

so far i have

```
public boolean isTheSame(String[] arr1, String[] arr2)
{
   if (arr1.length == arr2.length)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
       {
          if (arr1[i] == arr2[i])
          {
            return true;
          }
       }
    }
    return false;  
 }
```

The problem with this is that it only compares the first element of the two arrays.

Comment: Is the closing parenthesis on `if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]` there in your actual program?

Comment: For starters, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) on how to compare strings in java, and fix your compile time error (you forgot to close parenthesis on second if condition).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are iterating until you find a match. You should instead be looking for a String which doesn't match and you should be using `equals`  not `==`

```
// same as Arrays.equals()
public boolean isTheSame(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        if (!arr1[i].equals(arr2[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

FYI This is what Arrays.equals does as it handle `null` values as well.

```
public static boolean equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        Object o1 = a[i];
        Object o2 = a2[i];
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Solid answer. It always pays to take a look at the library implementation first.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isTheSame(String[] arr1, String[] arr2)
{
    if (arr1.length == arr2.length)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
          {
             if ((arr1[i] != null && arr2[i] != null && !arr1[i].equals(arr2[i]))
                 || (arr1[i] != null && arr2[i] == null) || 
                 (arr2[i] != null && arr1[i] == null))
              {
                return false;
              }
          }
    } else {
         return false;  
    }
    return true;  
 }
```

But it is very unoptimal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will only compare the first element. Look what it is doing:

```
public boolean isTheSame(String[] arr1, String[] arr2)
{
    if (arr1.length == arr2.length)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
          {
             // if the elements are equal ..
             // (NOTE: this will only be true for INTERNED strings!!)
             if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]) // fixed typo
              {
                // .. then STOP LOOKING and RETURN TRUE
                // wait- WHY?
                return true;
              }
          }
          // searched everything- but still RETURN FALSE??
    }
    return false;  
 }
```

While the usage of `==` is not the problem with the provided example data due to string interning, it *will* bite you someday for real data. Don't use `==` for objects unless *identity equality* is desired.